# Load page with accordion open based on external link

Tags: jquery

I have read the posts that come up on this topic, but I am looking for some guideance as I am new to jQuery and this code was written before I came on board.

```
    <!--ORIGINAL CODE-->
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#hidden-content').hide();
        $('#hidden-content-reveal').click(function() {
        $('#hidden-content').slideToggle(400);
              return false;
                 });
                 });
       </script>
```

My code based on reading

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#hidden-content2').hide();
    $('#hidden-content-reveal2').click(function() {
    $('#hidden-content2').slideToggle(400);
  return false;
   });
   // current location has anchor
   if(location.hash) {
   // find accordion href ending with that anchor
   // and trigger a click
    $(".hidden-content-reveal2[href$='"+location.hash+"']").trigger('click');
    } ;
    });
    </script>
```

HTML I want to open

```
    <p><a href="#" title="Content continued..." class="readMore accordion" id="hidden-content-reveal" name="hidden-content-reveal">Endangered Species Act Basics &raquo;</a></p>
    <div id="hidden-content">
    <p><a href="#top">&laquo; Back to the top</a></p>

      BLAH BLAH BLAH
    </div>
```

I want to open the HTML using something like www.address.com/page.php#hidden-content-reveal. It moves to the accordion section, highlights the link but does not expand the content. I know this has to be something simple I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided that the event handler is properly bound try this:

```
if (location.hash != '') {
 $(".hidden-content-reveal2[href='"+location.hash+"']").trigger('click');
}
```

OR

```
if (location.hash != '') {
 $(".hidden-content-reveal2[href='"+location.hash+"']").click();
}
```

Also, remove the return false in the click event handler, since that is the same as event.preventDefault(). That means that whatever element id is specified in the href attribute will not be added as a hash in the url